# Хранение данных в таблице

Tags: html, css

Есть данные, которые приходят с сервера и помещаются в таблицу.
Если строка слишком большая, то переноса не происходит и поэтому данные обрезаются.
Как посоветуете поступить, чтобы более менее симпатично выглядело и вся информация была видна?

```css
#result-table {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%
}

td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```